# Ubuntu 20.04 is not showing the right resolution option

Tags: display-resolution

I'm kinda new in ubuntu, so be gentle, please

So, the problem is,I installed ubuntu 20.04 and was adjusting some details. In the Display options, the higher resolution i found was 1024x800, but my monitor is optimized in 1600x900. I found a way to put this resolution. It looks something like in [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/) post.

So far it works just fine, but when I play steam games, this resolution I forced (1600x900) don't show up in the game's options. So it end up looking awful.

What can I do?